# Any idea to update list of data with better way?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5

Using Laravel 5.5 and eloquent.
Now i got a lot of data list with number.
Example Data actually have more than 100 data:
user_wallets

```
--------------------------
|id | points | use_point |
--------------------------
|1  | 10.2   | 502.22    |
|2  | 32.6   | 23.3      |
|3  | 33     | 1020.32   |
--------------------------
```

any idea to update the point in better ways?
let say, I want to update all point with * 0.55.
below is my current ways, but it slows.
and this calculation is updated with some offer date.

```
$rate = $request->rate; //0.55
$wallets = UserWallet::all();
foreach($wallets as $wallet)
{
   UserWallet::find($wallet->id)->update(['points'=>$wallet->points*$rate])
}
```

any idea to make it faster? or better way to do this update?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `each()` method as $wallets is a collection.

So:

```
$rate = $request->rate; //0.55
$wallets = UserWallet::all();
$wallets->each(function($item, $key) use(&$rate){
    $item->update(['points' => $item->points*$rate])
});
```

It's not a whole lot different than a foreach but I think it's the "Eloquent" way.

Comment: Noted and thanks. I will try this before getting more better ways because currently every time it updates, the server getting slow.